# VLookup not returning the results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm not sure why my `VLOOKUP` formula is not working like the screenshot below. The value is right there as highlighted. I want to output the value in Column G, but changing the 3rd parameter to 1 or 2 doesn't work.

Help is appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

Formula: =`VLOOKUP(B2,$F$1:$G$421,2,FALSE)`

[image]

Comment: Not that this solves your problem but the column index is one-based. Sou you probably want `=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$1:$G$421,2,FALSE)` (with a `2`), if you're looking to get the value out of `G`..

Comment: Yes I tried that too but didn't work...

Comment: Try this: `=VLOOKUP(ABS(B2),$F$1:$G$421,2,0`. Your values in B are text not numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you may want to look at.

I notice your data is left justified and that's normally the case for textual rather than numeric fields - it's *possible* to left justify numerics but it's neither the default nor the general practice.

If they *are* textual, there's a chance one or more of them may have leading or trailing spaces. That would prevent the lookup from finding a match.

Select (in turn) `B2` and `F1` and use the arrow keys in the formula box to check this is not the case.

In cases like this, I tend to (temporarily) set `B2` to the formula `=F1` just to see if it can find a match that's guaranteed (then use <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> to revert).

If that change results in the lookup working then obviously the (original) `B2` and `F1` are *not* the same value, and you need to work out why (hidden spaces, wrong types, and so on).

Comment: Thanks... for some reason the spreadsheet is so stuborn that I cannot mass change the column type to numbers or text or vice versa... I had to re-copy paste the values into a text page and it's working now... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing text to number (see the green triangle in your value cell). You have to convert the value in your source cell or matching cells to same type. To convert source to number use excel function such as int or value. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert text to number format is to multiply by 1 and then replace original text values with these new number values...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing lookup where you have a mix of text and numbers (i.e. looking up a text version of a number in a list of real numbers) you can also make use of the `VALUE` function... this will convert numbers stored as text to real numbers.
Embed it like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(B2),$F$1:$G$421,1,FALSE)
```

If you have a mix of text numbers and text text to look up in numbers/text then you can do:

```
=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VALUE(B2),B2),$F$1:$G$421,1,FALSE)
```

to change numbers stored as text to numbers, but leave other text as is...